# pfSense not working properly on Azure VNet? What do i do?

Tags: firewalls, virtualization, azure, pfsense

I'm currently working on a project based on creating virtual networks and configuring a virtualized firewall (pfSense) along with access control. I was given this project idea in a cybersecurity subreddit and thought to give it a go since I wanted to understand azure networks, pfsense and active directory.

As I was working on this project, I realised that the pfSense setup (using netgate's pfSense+) being done was not the same as you would conventionally see in any pfsense setup. I could not add nor setup a LAN as everything defaulted to a WAN. I couldn't even ping from the pfSense VM to the other VM within its network.

Due to this I was unable to make this a general firewall able to lease out DHCP addresses to its network, as it failed to notice machines other than itself within the network.

For clarification, this is how I created things in my Azure environment:

1. Created a resource group, following this I then created a virtual network and a security group over the virtual network. The virtual network would already have a network named "default" having the classic "/24" subnet.
2. Created the pfSense VM and a Windows OS VM, both existing under the same network given by the virtual network's "default".
3. Did no other configuration as I had believed that both VMs were complete.

I'm not sure where I went wrong, whether if it was messing up the network interface option, or the subnetting. I don't know and would appreciate advice on this.

Comment: I don't see an information security problem here. Sounds more like a problem with a cloud setup and networking, which just happens to be done with some firewall as one of the VM setup. Try superuser.com instead.